# Datastage Repository pane

Tags: repository, datastage

Is it possible to have two repositories opened at the same time in datastage designer?

What I want to do is being able to work with two different repositories at the same time in one window. 
When I open the designer application, it asks for one repository connection automatically and opens the designer window for that connection. (Configurable through settings)

I can't open more than one designer application in my machine, but I need to work on two different repositories at the same time. Is there a way to have like, 2 repository tabs in only one designer window? I've already tried some things - looking for 'add new repository' - but didn't find a way so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple Designer windows should be possible (I work with multiple Designers all the time) - multiple repositories in a single Designer will not work.

If you cannot open multiple Desgners you should investigate with a administrtor of your OS I suggest as there is no limit from the InfoSphere siede I know of.

Comment: The way the repository pane looks, it makes we think it's possible to have additional tabs, at least in this version, which is an old one (8.7) so i'll have to keep closing and reopening to switch reps.